# MySQL table creation pro­blem

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cities` (
  `Country` CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `City` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `AccentCity` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Region` CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Population` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Latitude` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `Longitude` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  KEY `AccentCity` (`AccentCity`(5)),
  KEY `City` (`City`(5))
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE http://www.mywebsite.com/worldcitiespop.txt
  INTO TABLE `cities`
  FIELDS
    TERMINATED BY ','
  LINES
    TERMINATED BY '\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Hello everybody, I downloaded a world cities database from MaxMind’s website http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities. It is around 160MB. now the problem is that I can't put it in my database. The text contains more than 2 million rows and it starts like this:

```
Country,City,AccentCity,Region,Population,Latitude,Longitude
ad,aixas,Aixàs,06,,42.4833333,1.4666667
ad,aixirivali,Aixirivali,06,,42.4666667,1.5
ad,aixirivall,Aixirivall,06,,42.4666667,1.5
```

What's wrong with the query?

Comment: " i cat pt it in my mysql database" - if that means "I can't put it into my MySQL database", please be more specific: do you get any errors? Warnings?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any ability in MySQL to `LOAD DATA INFILE` via a URL as you've indicated there. You can `LOAD DATA INFILE` using a file on the server, or `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` using a file on your client machine, but neither lets you give a URL and have MySQL perform an HTTP request to get the file.